# How to fix position of thead with Scrolled tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I create a table with scrollable body with a fixed head with the each head is same in size as its associated column, and each column has a different width than other columns.

For example, I have this table

```css
  table thead tr {
  display: block;
}

table th,
table td {
  width: 100px; //fixed width
}

table tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto; //set tbody to auto
}
```

```html
 <table border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
      <td>Looooooong</td>
      <td>Very Looooooooooong</td>
      <td>short</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The header does not match its associated column in position and size. Is there a fix to my method or another approach to achieve my goal without this problem ?

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/ CSS only implementation.

Comment: @DanielShillcock For completeness' sake it might be appropriate to acknowledge the author or at least mention that this is not your work.

Comment: @BramVanroy Sorry. Thought that was obvious. This is literally the top link on google when searching for "Fixed header table". If I wanted to present my own work, I'd have answered the question and not commented.

Comment: It looks like the one. I'll try to apply it and see. Thank you so much